# WPF UserControl Modify Portion of Gradient

Tags: c#, wpf, button, user-controls, gradient

If I have a simple user control `Button` w/ a background like this...

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1" />
  <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Is there a way to expose one of the gradient stops such that the person using the control could modify just the first one (e.g. `Red`) and maintain the gradient to `Black`?

Comment: Modify the Offset? Color?

Comment: So from the client side utilizing the control (e.g. `<MyCustom:Button>`) how would modify that property?

Comment: Is this something that the user would change in real time using something like a color selector/slider, or could it be something like user selects a color from a drop down list and the red is replaced with the new color.  Both are theoretically possible, although the latter option is much easier to implement and less taxing on your software.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in the UserControl or the MainWindow

Comment: in the MainWindow xaml, w/ the usage `newb` described below, that's what I'm trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will presume that you mean to have the user set the gradient stop color as part of their own XAML? If so, you can use a `DependencyProperty` and bind the `GradientStop.Color` to it.

In UserControl.cs :

```
    public CoolControl()
    {
        InitalizeComponent();
        SetValue(ColorProperty, Colors.Red); // or any default color
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(CoolControl)); // replace CoolControl with the name of your UserControl

    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

In UserControl.xaml :

```
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:CoolControl}}}" Offset="1" /> <!-- replace my:CoolControl with your namespace declaration and UserControl name -->
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Using the control:

```
    <Grid>
        <my:CoolControl BackgroundColor="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, the usage is what I want. It's building but not working. My button just goes fro white to black.

Also, in the `UserControl.xaml`, what namespace would I have like you have `my` but I'm inside the control wouldn't it just be `CoolControl`?

Comment: No, even within the control, in order to check against the type of the control (in my example "CoolControl") you have to import the Namespace that encapsulates the definition of your control.

Comment: I see now, yea that worked. Thank you. The only thing that doesn't work is the default color ` : Colors.Red`, the button just ends up black. Does the control automatically get the property value at start? If I add `GradientColor = Colors.Red` to the constructor, it works.

Comment: You are correct. It turns out that Colors are apparently White (not null) if not initialized or something. My default color when I tested was White, so I didn't notice. Apologies. Answer has been edited. Glad I could help!